# On Span Click - Insert rows into MySQL with page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've got a page where I display rows from MySQL table.

```
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
   <p> 
      <span class="label label-primary">
         <?php echo ($row2["miasto"]);  ?>
      </span> 
      <span class="label label-primary delete" id="<?php echo ($row2["miasto"]);  ?>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> 
   </p>
```

on a span click **.delete** I would like to get this row deleted from a database and page refreshed without those rows and with alert to be present.

I'm able to do a on click action in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".delete").click(function () {
$.post( "miastousun.php", { mdu: (this.id)} );
```

and than on php of miastousun.php:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM miasta_zmiany WHERE Miasto_dodaj='".($_POST['mdu'])."";
```

but does not seem to work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Eddited with getting to the point quicker.

Comment: when you click delete send an Ajax request to server to delete and load the table again.

Comment: That's still not a question. That's just a list of requirements.

Comment: You don't need to have the page load again. Send an AJAX request and have the JS on successful return modify the DOM so element(s) is/are removed. Here's the jquery tutorial, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: What exactly do you expect `$(".dete")` to match?

Comment: I just want it to delete a row in mysql database when clicked - that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ajax code.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.delete', function() {
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'miastousun.php?mdu='+thisId,              
          success: function(data){
            alert('Message something');
          },
          error: function(errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've got success message but no action is taken on mysql side - like the post is not ging through or I'm not calling it properly.

Comment: url: 'miastousun.php?mdu='+this.id,

Comment: var thisId = $(this).attr('id'); url: 'miastousun.php?mdu='+thisId,

Comment: it worked.... it was the syntax error in the mysql delete statement (in the end of post variable) I wouldn't get this without your help. Thanks!